# UnityContainer and Constructor Parameters

Tags: unity-container, design-patterns

I have an "Adapter" class that wraps an object called "X_Session". This adpater expects an ILogger and ICacheManager.

The way I thought of it is by defining this class with Unity and let it resolve both interfaces that are put in as constructor inputs.

What about the X_Session object? It is not registered by Unity, as I need to create it myself because its constructor requires input parameters that I gather from QueryString.

Do I resolve the Adpater class then set the X_Session object? Other better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, with an abstract factory is simple:

```
public interface IAdapterFactory {
   Adapter Create(ISession session);
}

public class AdapterFactoryImpl : IAdapterFactory  {
   public AdapterFactoryImpl(IDependency dep) {
       this._dep = dep;
   }

   public Adapter Create(ISession input) { 
     return new Adapter(_dep, input);
   }
}
```

You have to register in Unity only the factory.

Comment: Thanks Onof :). The problem is the X_Session object has no interface. It belongs to an existing API I am using. So maybe, as our colleague below suggested, I register the Adapter with Unity together with the X_Session input in the constructor and inject manually the X_Session. What do you think?

Comment: Guess I misunderstood your point! I don't let Unity know anything about ISession. It only brings me a instance of IAdpaterFactory and let the application inject ISession or Session object into the Adpater constructor. What about the Adpater don't I need to register it in Unity? And why?

Comment: You can't register the adapter in Unity if it needs the session object to be constructed and Unity doesn't know anything about it. You need the factory because the adapter needs an input not resolvable by Unity.

Comment: Hi Onof, Once the Adpater class is created by the factory, what is the best way to keep a reference to it throughout the application? Same question applies when I resolve a named instance from Unity, how to keep a reference to it to be used later? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be registering the X_Session object inside the Unity container at runtime, then having Unity injecting all the dependencies.

Comment: As I said, the X_session object needs to be created by a constructor that accepts inputs. Those inputs, the application itself needs to inject them as they are retrieved from QueryString and others from Database.

Comment: ok, but you can create it then registering inside Unity. Once you've done this, you can create the Adapter class and Unity will also inject X_Session dependencies.

Comment: @Simone this is unsafe. When a new session start you will overwrite the existing instance in the container.

Comment: I missed this point :(. Yes, since the X_Session needs application intervention, I can create it as some point, register it, then it could be injected to the constructor of Adapter class. Thanks for hte information. Much appreciated.

Comment: True Onof, at every Web request I create a new Session. Is this unsafe?

Comment: @bhaidar, It's unsafe to register it in Unity once created

Comment: @onof you can register more than one instance for type.